# Publishing a webservice on default webserver

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I'm looking for some advice regarding a webservice.

I currently have 3 websites that do the same thing, just with a different branding. Each of the website integrates with a third party site via a webservice and there's quite a lot of config goes into each site.

All 3 sites are on the same server, each has it's own IP and runs under HTTPS.

I would like to move functionality to a central website and access it from my other websites via my own webservice. My initial thoughts are to create a new website using the default webserver as it's only internal to the sites, but it's the first time I've done something like this so I'm not entirely clear.

I've a few questions that I still haven't found the answer to, so would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Can this be done via the default website?
Do I need a separate IP from the ones currently allocated to my 3 sites?
Do I need another domain name or will localhost suffice?
Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You start by saying that you have a couple of questions, but you only asked one (with a few sub questions). Which is good. Because SO requires one question at-a-time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question gives a lot to think about.  However, the quick answer is "yes". If you make a web service for yourself, you can host it on localhost, on the same server as your three web sites.  You don't need any web address or IP address.  Hard to believe that it is actually that simple, but for a locally hosted web service, it is.

After reading your entire question, it seems like your challenges will eventually be logical ones (once you run the traffic of three sites, into one WS).  I'm sure you already know that.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes you're right with your final comment - for instance I may choose to host the feeder sites on separate servers and so on. However, you've given me the information I needed to dig further, so I'm happy to accept your answer.